# Is it possible to SELECT a tag within an Azure SQL Database?

Tags: sql-server, azure, t-sql, azure-sql-database

I'm running a simple query on an Azure SQL Database:

```
SELECT name
    ,database_id
    ,compatibility_level
FROM sys.databases
```

I would like to add to that some Azure `tags` so I can see if the environment is on test/dev/prod:

[image]

Would it be possible to retrieve tags from within an Azure SQL Database?

Or do I need to do such job with PowerShell or Kusto?

Answer (score 1):

We need to perform job in power shell.
I run the below command in power shell to retrieve the tags of database

```
Get-AzTag -ResourceId /subscriptions/<subscriptionid>/resourcegroups/<resource group name>/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/<sql server name>/databases/<database name>
```

Here is the output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. But this is the confirmation that the only way to archive so is by doing it outside the database (PowerShell). Inside the database (T-SQL) we cannot retrieve the Tag.

Comment: Yes, we can retrieve the tags of database by doing outside the database